# Show that $(1+x)^n>\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ for all $x>0, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: inequality

Show that $(1+x)^n>\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ for all $x>0, n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

I actually have no idea how to start - I've expanded the left side to get:

$1+{n\choose 1}x+{n\choose 2}x^2+...+x^n$

What's the general technique/method for these sort of show that x>y questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, I've proved it is true for $n \geq 2$ as the RHS is contained in the LHS after that and the LHS only has addition, but how do I prove it for $n=1$? Am I aiming to show that $1+nx>\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$

Comment: For $n=1$ simply 1+x>0 which is true.